# Left join brainfart

Tags: sql

I seem to be thinking wrong today. I have two tables as follows

```
+--------+  +------------------------+
|person  |  |contact                 |
+--------+  +-----------------+------+
|id |name|  |person_id |type  | value|
+--------+  +------------------------+
|00 |a   |  |00        |phone |123   |
|01 |b   |  |00        |email |a@a.a |
|02 |c   |  |01        |phone |456   |
|03 |d   |  |02        |email |c@c.c |
+--------+  +------------------------+
```

and I need **all** persons and **optionally** their phone number, e.g.

```
+-----------+
|name |phone|
+-----------+
|a    |123  |
|b    |456  |
|c    |     |
|d    |     |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: yes, this is a left join. What is the SQL you tried?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need a left join, but you need to include the restriction on the phone type in the join condition:

```
select p.*, c.value as phone
from person p 
  left join contact c 
         on c.person_id = p.id 
        and c.type = 'phone'
```

If you put the restriction `c.type = 'phone'` into the `where` clause, that would turn the outer join back into an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to select the phone information, put the criteria (`type = 'phone'`
) in `on` clause:

```
select p.name, c.value as phone
from person p left join contact c 
on p.id = c.person_id and
c.type = 'phone'
```

Comment: With the c.type condition in the WHERE clause, the LEFT JOIN will return regular INNER JOIN result. Move the condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.